# How can I import data from D365 ERP (AxDB) database to PowerBI AxDW database in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I want to import the database from D365 ERP database to PowerBI AxDW database in SSMS, I have tried all the possible ways to do it, still not able to get the data.

Here's the some of the methods I tried to import data below:

1. I have logged into the Power BI desktop and while opening the reports, I didn't see any data and when I'm opening it in D365F&O, I'm able to see the data on reports.

[image: Image : Blank data in Power BI Desktop]

2. So I thought to import data from D365F&O database then I created new database AxDW to store the data for Power BI.

[image: Image : AxDW (new database to store the imported data)]

3. On the Power BI desktop, clicked on **Get Data** and selected **ODataFeed** I have changed the URL to cloud.sigerp.dynamics.com/data and started importing the data.

[image: Image : Steps]

4. And once the importing stopped, got a popup error message saying the url is not correct and not able to import the data from sigerp.
5. After that I clicked on **SQL Server database** and entered the url and database address and clicked Ok, and after loading for some time, still getting the error saying Url is incorrect and not able to import the data.
   [image: Image : SQL server database]
6. I have tried with the Transform Data > Data Source settings

[image: Data Source Settings]

Please help me with importing data from D365 ERP to Dw data base.

Comment: Not really sure you have come to the best place with this question as it is not programming related, nor iit is about a problem unique to software development. I would probably ask dynamics support.

Comment: Why don't you connect Power BI to d365 via the dataverse? To move data from D365 to SQL Server you'll need to export the data via D365 data management to the sql server. Look at BYOD https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/analytics/export-entities-to-your-own-database